# Looking for a dataset that contain string value in Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, dataset

I'm learning Machine Learning with Tensorflow. I've work with some dataset like Iris flower data and Boston House, but all those data's values was float.
Yes I'm looking for a dataset that contain data's values are in string format to practice. Can you give me some suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: Tks Prune. Actually I have problems when working with new dataset which contains string data and haven't find any guide for it. Yep next time I'll make my question more specific.

Answer (score 2):

I provide you just two easy-to-start places:

1. Tensorflow website has three very good tutorials to deal with word embedding, language modeling and sequence-to-sequence models. I don't have enough reputation to link them directly but you can easily find them [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/). They provide you with some tensorflow code to deal with human language
2. Moreover, if you want to build a model from scratch and you need only the dataset, try [ntlk corpora](http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/). They are easy to download directly from the code.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's [ParlAI](https://github.com/facebookresearch/ParlAI) project lists a good amount of datasets for Natural Language Processing tasks

[IMDB's reviews](https://www.kaggle.com/deepmatrix/imdb-5000-movie-dataset) dataset is also a classic example, also [Amazon's reviews](https://www.kaggle.com/bittlingmayer/amazonreviews) for sentiment analysis. If you take a look at kernels posted on Kaggle you'll get a lot of insights about the dataset and the task.